# RequestFiltering not working for MS-DOS device name paths

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, pci-compliance, requestfiltering

I'm trying to appease a PCI scan failure we recently had done, in which it states:

> Microsoft ASP.NET MS-DOS Device Name DoS
>
> Synopsis :
> A framework used by the remote web server has a denial of service vulnerability.
> Impact:
> The web server running on the remote host appears to be using Microsoft
> ASP.NET, and may be affected by a denial of service vulnerability. Requesting a URL
> containing an MS-DOS device name can cause the web server to become
> temporarily unresponsive.

In a nutshell, we visit a URL on our app such as `/AUX/.aspx` we get a 500 error.

I'm using RequestFiltering to filter these requests out, and return 404's instead, without the server trying to process the request.

An excerpt of my web.config is below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>
                <add sequence="/AUX/.aspx" />
            </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

However, this isn't working, it's still returning a 500.

I would expect it to return a 404.

If I add the following catch-all url to the `denyUrlSequences` then the whole site produces the expected 404.

```
<add sequence="/" />
```

It's worth mentioning the application in question is an MVC app running on IIS 7.5 (Windows 2008 R2)

Comment: Have figured out a slight workaround - by removing the `<customErrors>` block, it works as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to solve this problem.

My solution was to disable .Net Error Pages and enable IIS Error Pages.

When you move the custom error handling from the higher .Net level to the lower IIS level the HTTP response code changes from 500 to 404.

PCI Test Passed :-)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for quite some time myself. I think the 500 response code is correct for MS-DOS names in the URL, and you do not need to add anything to request filtering.

You'll notice that you will get a 500 error if you use any of the MS-DOS names (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/74496) without doing anything to your configuration. However, if you add a RequestFiltering denySequence for something else, like "foo", then you will see the 404.5 error when browsing to /foo.

If you add relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" to the [httpRuntime element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.relaxedurltofilesystemmapping(v=vs.110).aspx) along with your request filtering denySequence entries, then you will get the 404.5 for MS-DOS names.

But disabling the default asp.net configuration just so you can get something other then a 500 response for a URL with MS-DOS name is a rediculous request from a PCI compliance check.