# Tenable Nessus to approve PCI DSS: Microsoft ASP.NET MS-DOS Device Name DoS (PCI-DSS check)

Tags: asp.net, azure-web-app-service, pci-compliance, nessus

[RequestFiltering not working for MS-DOS device name paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809485/requestfiltering-not-working-for-ms-dos-device-name-paths)

I have the same question but I have one app service in Azure.
This was scanned by Tenable Nessus to approve PCI DSS
CVE: CVE-2007-2897
BID: 51527
EDB-ID: 3965
Medium 64589 Microsoft ASP.NET MS-DOS Device Name DoS (PCI-DSS check)

My app in Azure has IIS 10, but I don´t know where can I make that zolution like an IIS normal.

There is someone that could help my with the answer this PCI vulnerability?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, (but sorry about my English)
Last scan (Nessus scan) I did, to azure app service, where we have our web applications, we found this vulnerabilities:

https://www.tenable.com/plugins/nessus/64589

Comment: I hope the following help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/
and check the comment here
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/835939-iis-6-isapi-filter-for-ms-dos-device-names